# How to run a command that will reset the network interfaces in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to run a command on remote machine. The command will reset the network interfaces. How to run this in ansible playbook

```
- name: Execute config command
  sudo: yes
  shell: "mycommand"
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  ignore_errors: true
```

The above task is not working consistently. Even I tried with `async: 300`, the same inconsistency is being observed.

Comment: What kind of inconsistencies are you seeing? Does "mycommand" consistently return OK when run manually?

Comment: Also can you describe what you're exactly doing in the shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely running into a situation similar to the one I describe [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955605/how-to-reboot-centos-7-with-ansible/29962644#29962644). Depending on the command you are running (`mycommand`) the network connection is likely dropping very quickly, causing Ansible to think that the connection was dropped unexpectedly.  When this happens it will cause Ansible to treat it as an error.

You likely want to modify `mycommand` to include a sleep for a few seconds before the reset occurs, and continue using `async:0` and `poll:0`.  This will give Ansible enough time to launch `mycommand` into the background and cleanly disconnect from the server without error before the server resets the network connection.

Depending on what your next task is you may also want to include a `wait_for` task that runs via `local_action` to ensure Ansible waits for this network reset to complete before attempting any other tasks.