# Why does my remote host return a error code -1 when I use fabric reboot()?

Tags: python, linux, bash, fabric

Local Host Environment: CentOS 7, Python 3.5.1, Fabric3 (1.11.1.post1)
Remote Host Environment: CentOS 7

fibfile:

```
def fuc():
    reboot()
```

bash:

```
fab -f fibfile.py -H host -u root -p password
```

The remote host did reboot but returns a fatalError:

```
sudo() received nonzero return code -1 while executing 'reboot'!
```

Now I use `warn_only` to prevent failure:

fabfile:

```
def test():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        reboot()
```

Comment: Do you get shell on the remote host after performing: the following command: "ssh host -l root" and then enter the password?

Comment: No. I test fibfile with just one api : reboot() also get fatalerror above. Fabric can login success with password I set in fab command.

Comment: Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1488)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a similar question when use ansible: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29955605/4905806)

I think the top answer is right:

> `reboot` is shutting down the server so quickly that the server is tearing down the SSH connection.

`shutdown -r now` return the same fatal error:

> sudo() received nonzero return code -1 while executing 'shutdown -r now'!

`shutdown -r +1` return success:

> out: Shutdown scheduled for Mon 2016-05-23 14:16:48 UTC, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.

But shutdown can only delay at least one minute.
So we can only choose to wait for a minute or ignore the error.

Answer (score 5):

I started having this problem with some new virtual machines. I think they do shut down too fast, as Jon Stark said.

To fix it, I ignore the error and the warning, like this.

```
with settings(hide('warnings'),
              warn_only=True,
             ):
    sudo("shutdown -r now")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a shell session into the background which sleeps for 1 second then executes the `reboot` command. Must be done without the use of `nohup` command because of the [nohup issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775598/start-a-background-process-with-nohup-using-fabric). I use `tmux`...

```
reboot(command='tmux new-session -d "sleep 1; reboot;"')
```